# Is it possible to use curses only to read a keypress but nothing else?

Tags: python, python-2.7, curses

I have some python code that is not using curses. Maybe at some point I will change that and use curses throughout all the code. However, now this is not an option.

I was looking for how to read a single keypress in linux and the only feasible solution I found was using curses. However, I don't know if it is possible to use curses only to read a key, but otherwise not interfere with my terminal.

I tried this

```
def get_key_via_ncurses_impl(win):
    return win.getkey()         
def get_key_via_ncurses():
    x = curses.wrapper(get_key_via_ncurses_impl)
    print(x)
    return x
```

..but when called it clears the screen and only after the key was pressed I get to see the original screen again (with the output for which I didnt use curses).

I also tried this:

```
def get_key_via_ncurses():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    x = get_key_via_ncurses_impl(stdscr)
    print(x)
    return x
```

in the hope that `curses.initscr()` will not clear the screen, but it does and of course not properly cleaning up will leave my terminal in a messy state.

**Is it possible to use curses to read a single key, but keep the rest of the output "uncursed"?** If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) module if you only need to process key presses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`filter`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter) function (called before `initscr`) tells curses to limit its updates to a single line.   The python binding includes [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter).

Here's an example:

```
import curses

curses.filter()
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
foo = stdscr.getkey()
print("result:" + foo)
```

Comment: this seems to be the right tool, unfortunately calling `getkey` still clears the whole screen

Comment: if I put some print statement before, then `getkey` will clear the screen, no matter if I call `filter` or not. I do believe that it works, because thats also what I understand from the documentation, just not for me :(. I am now considering to either get my key without curses or switch to using curses for all io